# JSONLP and JQuery, returning undefined

Tags: jquery, json, json-ld

Sorry, not well versed in this but pulling hair out at this point.
I have on page JSON, I am trying to return a simple value, like "mpn".

The JSON is pretty simple:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">

    {
       "@context":"http://schema.org/",
       "@type":"Product",
       "mpn": "examplempn"
       "offers":[
          {
             "@type":"Offer",
             "itemCondition":"http://schema.org/NewCondition",
             "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
             "sku":"examplesku"
          },
          {
             "@type":"Offer",
             "itemCondition":"http://schema.org/NewCondition",
             "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
             "sku":"examplesku"
          }
    ],
       "aggregateRating":{
          "ratingValue":"5",
          "reviewCount":"5"
       }
    }

</script>
```

The jQuery is as follows:

```
var json = ($('script[type="application/ld+json"]').text());
$('#display').html('testing:' + json["mpn"] + '</p>');
```

I can return the variable json just fine.  But I cannot get the value of a node.  This always comes up as undefined.  I have tried JSON.parse, but it just does not work. I obviously do not understand a core concept here, I am just looking for someone to push me in the right direction.  thank you in advance!

Comment: I suspect your json is a string, it needs to be converted to an object with JSON.parse()